# Enabling Firebase persistence data returns weird result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a refresh button that reloads posts on the screen. However, I am finding that when firebase persistence data is set to true, the refresh does not return exactly what I wanted unless I refreshed it twice?

Here is the code

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(postKey).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {                
        if postKey == "-KQtLYEDA5FiYmcR5sVm" {
                print(postDict["commentCount"])
            }
```

I am checking a single entry in my firebase database with the above code. With the breakpoint set just after the print statement below is the result

1. The comment count initially is 0 in the database and on my screen as expected. I change the entry manually to 100 and hit refresh, the comment count is printed out to be 0 still. However, when I hit refresh again, this time the commentCount returns 100 which is what I wanted.
2. I tried doing the above experiment with persistence disabled and the result is exactly what I would expected with the first return to be 100 straight away.

As a side question, my whole app is designed around observeSingleEventOfType, I was wondering how would enabling, disabling persistence data affect how data is loaded, reloaded, updated?

Comment: When you're using persistence, new observers will immediately fire with the value from the cache and then later fire again with the latest value from the server. By using `observeSingleEventOfType` you're ignoring the second/fresh value. For this reason it is best to not mix disk persistence with `observeSingleEventOfType`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase

Comment: That explains it really well!