# Retrieving data in firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am a beginner in firebase and in iOS. I am trying to change a project from parse to firebase.I successfully created and updated the firebase database. But while trying to retrieve data from firebase its just not working for me.
Here's the code I used.

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
[[[ref child:@"users"] child:userID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@",snapshot.value);
    // Get user value
}withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

The control just skips the whole block. I can't figure out the problem.
The firebase guide is very hard to understand. Please tell me how to get values to a dictionary from a firebase child.

Comment: There can be many reasons the block is being skipped, but I would start by printing the description userID and then printing the description of the database reference you're observing to make sure you're observing the path in the database that you intend to.

Comment: can you tell me how tor retrieve data from firebase using objective-c. In simple way.

Comment: If you have persistence enabled, use the live listener method "[[[ref child:@"users"] child:userID] observeEventOfType: ...]". Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseReference database = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    database.child("notes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List notes = new ArrayList<>();
     for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Note note = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Note.class);
    notes.add(note);
    }
   adapter.updateList(notes);
   }
   ...
   });
```