# Firebase returning data from one database but not the other Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have two sub sections in my root database, users and userSelfies[image]

[image]

I use the users section to store the id of the profile picture, and the userSelfies section to store the actual download links. 
I made a general purpose function to retrieve data from any path in the database. It looks like this:

```
static func getDatabaseEntry(path: String, key: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ return: AnyObject?, _ error: String?) -> Void) {

    databaseReference.child(path).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //print("snapshot: ", snapshot)


        dump((snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]))

        if let value =  (snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject])?[key] {
            print("unwrapped snapshot dict value from key: ", value)

            completionHandler(value,  nil)

        }else{
            print("no value for key \(key) so setting return as nil")
            completionHandler(nil,  nil)

        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completionHandler(nil,  error.localizedDescription)


    }


}
```

Now for some strange reason, when using this function on the 'users' section of the database, it returns as expected, a couple of milliseconds delay. However, when using this exact same function with a different path parameter that leads to the userSelfies download link, the function returns nil. I have tried dump() on the snapshot, and I manually tried to find the selfie ID key. It returned the dictionary of all the database entries EXCEPT for the most recent (or just any recent) entries. I then checked on the website to make sure that the data was actually there in the database, reloaded the page, and sure enough it was there.

That means the Firebase SDK observeSingleEvent must be the problem. However, I just cannot figure out why it would work and update quickly for one section of the database, but not the other. In fact, the users section contains more information and is larger! So if anything that should be slower? Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: please someone help i've been trying everything for like 12 hours now...i even tried switching to normal observe and removing the handle but it's impossible to remove the handle firebase seems broken

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. A day later and I figured it out. Thanks a lot firebase docs for explaining this. 
Because firebase counts a listen to local cache as an observation, trying to remove the listener as soon as it has completed one listen will not work as it won’t have had a second chance to read from the actual cloud. therefore, only remove the listener once leaving the scene or something that gives it enough time to fully query the cloud. However, if the cached data is the same as the server data, then it will not ‘observe’ the server data, it will only do one observation on the cached data, and therefore there will only be one observation event.
I managed to figure the last bit out with the help of this post: [What actually happens when persistence is enabled in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase)