# Firebase query not working when Persistence is Enabled in Firebase Realtime Database iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios11

Firebase query not working when Persistence is Enabled in Firebase Realtime Database iOS (Swift)

Using Firebase (4.1.1)
Using FirebaseDatabase (4.0.2)

Xcode Version 9.0
iOS Base Sdk iOS 11.0

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Query is working fine when persistence is turned to false

sample query :

```
ref.child("user").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue:"john")
   .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { (snapshot) in
});
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what exactly is not working the way you expect?

Comment: snapshot do exists when the persistance is disabled and all the users with name john is retrieved  but when persistance is set to true snapshot do not exists if any writes happen within the app after user login but when the app is reinstalled it will show the users but if a user with name john is added in that installation it is not reflected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What actually happens when persistence is enabled in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase)

Comment: I faced a similar issue.  There is no clean solution.  I just used the observe method and then removed the observer after i obtained the data I needed.  You could also try looking into keeySynced.

Comment: thank you @rMickeyD ,  adding keep synced to database reference solved the issue

Comment: Do i want to add keeysync when the open so as to make data synchronized and do this add any pressure to the database.