# How to save a part of firebase realtime database in offline mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

I wanted to store the specific path in Firebase database (JSON) in local phone storage, not all data at the realtime-Firebase database. Say I have a news-feed path for each user in my Firebase-database and I want to save only the news-feed which is specified for the user instead of loading whole useless data on the local storage of user's mobile.

I read this paragraph from the official [Firabase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) which mentioned that

> The Firebase Real-time Database synchronizes and stores a local copy of the data for active listeners. In addition, you can keep specific locations in sync.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
    scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

If this is the solution to my question, then I can use this line directly without writing that line

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two bits of code are not really related.  They don't do the same thing.

`keepSynced(true)` effectively keeps a listener active on the given reference, from the moment it's called, for as long as the app is running, so that the local version of the data is always in sync with the remote version on the server.

`setPersistenceEnabled(true)` just activates local caching of the data read by the SDK.  When persistence is enabled, the app can still query data previously read.  It takes effect for all data read by the SDK.  While persistence is enabled, you can't control which data is cached - all read data is cached up to 10MB max.  When the max is reached the oldest data will be evicted from the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so how to make firebase load specific ref from database instead of whole database

Comment: Just listen to the ref you want to load.  The entire database is not synchronized unless you listen to the root ref.

Comment: ammm, yes I know that but by calling `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` the whole database will be store on the mobile and I want to avoid this process as my database is so big  and I just want to parse a small part, and avoid loading/using useless data/memory

Comment: You're misunderstanding - please read my answer again.  When persistence is enabled, only the data that is actually read is cached locally, and you don't get to choose which read data is cached when persistence is enabled.

Comment: but I read something else at many topics which say that the `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` method is not only allow caching but also loading data on disk once any observer is called. 
check that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase 
sorry for my questions but I want to be sure about this topic

Comment: I don't understand.  This sounds like a different question than the one you originally asked.

Comment: I think I have misunderstanding... I can't call `keepSynced(true)` without call `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` at first, is that right? 
If I called `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` the application will cache whole database from server to local storage to retrieve it again at offline mode, if I called `keepSynced(true)` at my code for specific root, then this root will be sync with offline data updates. 
is there a wrong in these processes? 
If not, then I want to avoid the first process which is caching whole database on the local storage, I just want to load only that root.

Comment: Please read my answer again.  keepSynced is not really related to persistence.  keepSynced is just adds a listener that synchronizes data with client like any other listener.  The listening stops after the app process is killed.  Persistence determines if any synchronized data (no matter how it's read) is saved on disk for future use, even after the app process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best way will be to parse the Firebase JSON data and map it into an object and then save only data that you need in a local storage (News-feed in your case), and then access it later whenever you need it.

For this, you can use Paper DB as a local storage to store specific data and use it whenever you need to. It stores data as a key value pair so you can access your data with the same key you inserted it with in the database. (Just like shared preferences work).
It stores data as cache in your local storage and uses Kryo serialization framework which is pretty fast for I/O operations.

Or you can also use Room (a google library) with SQLite to achieve this task.
Haven't tried Room but i think it will suite your purpose.
Here's the official documentation for [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: yes, this is a solution too, but I want to know if there exist a solution by current database-server instead of creating a local database

Comment: @MohamedNagyMostafa did u find any solution?